# Continuous expected value of modular minimum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I have a simulation in which I generate $n$ uniformly distributed values $X_i$ where $0 \le X_i \le s-1$. Given the minimum of these $n$ values being $M_n=min\{X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1}\}$ I calculated the general form of the expected value of that quantity $E[M_n]$ partially using the known discrete probability and a sum:
$$
p(x)=\left(\frac{s-x}{s}\right)^n-\left(\frac{s-x-1}{s}\right)^n \\
E[M_n]=\sum_{x=0}^{s-1} x*p(x)
$$

While this works I am mostly interested in the case where $s$ is much greater than $n$ and both are fairly large values (nearly continuous, around $10^{100}$ for $s$) meaning this form is very slow to compute. To accommodate that I empirically found a simple form which is an exact fit as far as I can tell for values of $n \gt 0$, though I am not sure how I would have gotten it mathematically from the discrete form (perhaps converting the probability to a PDF and integrating it?):
$$
\frac{s}{n+1}
$$

My actual question however pertains to finding a similar formula for the expected value of a similar distribution. Like before it has a uniformly distributed set of values $X_i$ where $0 \le X_i \le s-1$, but this time the operation on them starts with computing a modulus by a value $0 \lt m \le s$ like so: $Y_i=X_i \bmod m$. The minimum of these $n$ values is then taken like before: $M_n=min\{Y_0,\ldots,Y_{n-1}\}$, and the quantity I am interested in is the expected value $E[M_n]$ of this distribution.

For this distribution I did find the exact discrete probability as well and could calculate the expected value the same way:
$$
s_m=s^n * \left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{m}{s}\right)^n\right) \\
p(x)=\frac{\left(s-x\right)^n}{s_m}-\frac{\left(s-x-1\right)^n}{s_m} \\
E[M_n]=\sum_{x=0}^{m-1} x*p(x)
$$

Despite this however I have not been able to find a continuous solution similar to the simple form I found for the other distribution. I found a function fairly close to what I think the solution is just by guessing its form based on how the other simple function looked as both have the same asymptotic behavior with different y-intercepts, but the function I found slightly overestimates the value for low values of $n$:
$$
\frac{s}{n} * \left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{m}{2*s}\right)^n\right)
$$

What would the continious solution I am looking for be, or how would I go about finding it? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Here is a graph showing what these functions look like visually:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zhd7ogobsy

The solid lines graph the discrete expected value (they dip down on larger values I think due to being discrete, though I have not actually confirmed that yet for such large values of $n$ and $s$) whereas the dashed lines represent the continuous forms. The dashed line for the first standard function fits pretty much perfectly (ignoring the part where it dips down) whereas the modular function is fairly close but is slightly off near the start as mentioned previously.

To confirm this further, below are also some simulations I have run which calculate the expected value of each distribution (y axis) with $2^{16}$ samples for each $n$ (on the x axis) with $s=2^{64}$ and $m=2^{61}$. The blue circles represent the numerically estimated expected values whereas the green line represents the continuous functions mentioned previously.

Standard Minimum Expected Value (Good fit):
[image: Expected value of the minimum of values]

Modular Minimum Expected Value (Not so good fit):
[image: Expected value of the modular minimum of values]